# Firefox Mobile Layout Shift virtual keyboard using vh

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have my site split into sections that have a set height using vh. At the bottom is an input field and up until I focus the input field and the mobile keyboard appears everything is fine. But as soon as I tap out of the field, the keyboard disappearing leads to some kind of scroll position/layout shift problem, and the whole page flicks upwards so the user would have to scroll down again to see the input, instead of the input being back at the bottom of the viewport again.

Thanks in advance!

I have set up a minimalistic sandbox to showcase the problem, as I mentioned it only happens on Firefox mobile. I think it's due to Firefox resizing the viewport with the keyboard, does anyone know if this problem is solvable using css or do I need some JS hack for that use case?

I also try setting the interactice-widgets metatag to overlays-content but to no effect.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/affectionate-cloud-c2n8xn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.